# Set base url in Pimcore

Tags: php, docker, apache, pimcore

I've installed Pimcore via docker on server and exposed it via apache2 to https://example.com/pimcore/

Unfortunately the generated links and asset-sources are missing the base-url /pimcore/

I tried to set a base-url in every config including symphony but without any effect.

Is there any way to configure a base url?